# ubuntu hangs after starting with issue Pointer to Flat Panel Invalid message

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu, ubuntu-gnome

I am trying to install ubuntu 13.10 and i am having issues with the process.

After i install when i restart i get the message,
Pointer to Flat Panel Invalid message in dos screen and then gui loads but its very unresponsive and if i click on web browser or anything it just hangs and doesn't work at all.

Here is my configuration : Intel Core2Duo processor 2.2GHz, Dell flat monitor 17 inch, 4 gb of ram.

Anyone have idea about this? I tried to install ubuntu GNOME, XUBUNTU as i believed its the problem with UNITY but they have the same problem. I am really frustated now as i am not sure what to do because if i install windows it works fine :(

I also tried to install VGA Driver NVIDIA from additional drivers when i got lucky with 13.10 as system worked for a while. but when i rebooted it just crashed and hangs at the boot.

Thanks.
Hardik

Answer (score 1):

I finally found how to resolve this issue.
exact error was

> Nouveau Pointer to flat panel table invalid

I tried different distro's and issue was same.

after looking at details of Nouveau errors i did this, booted my system into safe mode. for those who have issue like me where system hangs don't open any window via mouse just press Ctrl+T which will open terminal and run following command,

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

This is for only system which have nvidia boards. and run

```
sudo reboot now
```

as if you move your mouse to reboot it will hang the system. and then when system runs press F10 or delete key to boot into bios,

Then change following options,(based on your bios it would be in one of submenu.

Enable VGA/Graphics slot
set it to 256 MB

then you reboot and enjoy your system :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem occured to me on Ubuntu 14.04 after I installed nvidia-prime.
I switched to a terminal window CTRL-ALT_F2 then after I did `sudo apt-get update` it told me that some package is not properly installed. So I did `sudo apt-get upgrade`. After it installed the package it triggered a series of updates and configurations all related to NVIDIA driver. After everything is done I rebooted and everything was back to normal.